# Convert X,Y coord to lane id and road coords

Tags: coordinate-system

Is there any way or function that can convert x,y coordinates to get s coordinate, road id and lane id? I need this info for making OpenScenario file, so want to convert x,y coord present in xodr.

Comment: What is a *"s coordinate"*? Is it a vertical coordinate i.e. height?

Comment: Which software are you working with?

Comment: I am using Sumo's netconvert to convert osm to xodr. In Road coordinates, we have s and t coordinates. s coord goes along the reference line of the road and t is perpendicular to s.